# Using three.js add animation to 3d avatar (.glb)

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I downloaded animation set from mixamo(.fbx)

Already i have 3d character with simple skeleton file(.glb),

Using three.js how can i add animation to this glb file.

I tried using https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/ but i could not get specific example for this

I tried with this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkPfhzIbp2g there was no exact shared code example for this

Any help on this would be great !

FYI:

```
    <html>
  
    <body>
    <div id="navbar"><span>Three.js </span></div>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module">

    import {GLTFLoader} from  'https://server:8000/sm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

   const loader = new GLTFLoader();
   loader.load( './model.glb', function ( gltf ) {
  scene.add( gltf.scene );


  }, undefined, function ( error ) {

  console.error( error );

  } );

   </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks
vij

Comment: Any website where i can upload my .glb file and add animation to it

Comment: Three.js does have a lot of examples for animation. This one uses a mixamo model for idle, walk and run animations: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=anim#webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending

Comment: Further reference for documentation on animation system: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=animation#manual/en/introduction/Animation-system